# Controlling Bluetooth headset v4.1 connection from an app

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth earphones v4.1 which connects directly from phone's bluetooth settings.
but i want to control their connection from a particular app only, that means they wont be able to connect from the mobile settings and will be connected only if the app is running in the background.

please help me solve it, can it be controlled with some changes at hardware firmware level or can be done from the app itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, `CoreBluetooth` is meant to connect only with Bluetooth Low Energy devices. Headsets are not BLE devices, so what you want cannot be done, at least not on iOS

Comment: Thanks alot, any idea for android?